# Passing parameter to Web API with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my web api but the post requests don't get through. It works just fine without a parameter but using one just does not work. I've been using the same method to pass parameters to a MVC action and that worked perfectly fine but the api just does not take it.

VideoController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void LikeVideo(uint videoID)
    {

    }
```

Link in html:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LikeVideo", "Video", new { httpRoute = "DefaultApi"})" class="RateVideo">
```

Ajax request:

```
    $(".RateVideo").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: { videoID: 123},

    });

});
```

Thanks in advance

Jan

Comment: Sounds like `void` inside `public void LikeVideo(uint videoID)` is wrong, try `public IHttpActionResult LikeVideo(uint videoID)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work i had to adjust the API action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("API/Video/LikeVideo")]
    public void LikeVideo([FromBody]uint videoID)
    {

    }
```

And the ajax had to be modified like this:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: JSON.stringify(@Model.VideoID),
        contentType: 'Application/json',
    });
```

This worked just as well:

```
    var videoID = 123;

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: JSON.stringify(videoID),
        contentType: 'Application/json',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get to the controller and post data to it. I would use this structure.

```
 //If 123 is an external parameter passed into the function 
 var json = '{videoID: ' + 123 + '}';

 $.ajax({
     url:'@Url.Action("LikeVideo", "Video")',
     type:'POST',
     data:json,
     contentType: 'Application/json',
     success:function(result){
         //Whatever
     }
 });
```

You could also use Json.Stringify instead of doing what I did here for the data.

EDIT: Also the void should either be an ActionResult or a JsonResult. Not a void

Comment: Thanks the json worked for me just had to adjust the action a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try following syntax:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'your url',
     type:'POST',
     data:JSON.stringify({videoID:123}),
     contentType: 'Application/json',
     success:function(result){
        //your code
     }
 });
```